# Calling a python program through MATLAB and accessing the same instance of python program everytime

Tags: matlab, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm calling a python program (steppermotor.py) from MATLAB R2014a using system call.
I'm calling python from MATLAB using such commands-

```
system('C:\Python33\python C:\PhidgetsPython\steppermotor.py initialize()');
```

the main script of steppermotor.py looks like this:

if **name** == '**main**':

```
if sys.argv[1] =='initialization()':
    initialization(1)

if re.search('CalibrationMIN',sys.argv[1]):
    val = (re.search(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",sys.argv[1]).group())

    print(val)
    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)

    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        if val >= str(0):
            x = CalibrationMIN(float(val))
            print(x)
            exit(x)
        else:
            print('Enter a positive value as input argument')
            exit(3)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)


if re.search('CalibrationMAX',sys.argv[1]):
    val = (re.search(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",sys.argv[1]).group())

    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)
    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        if val >= str(0):
            x = CalibrationMAX(float(val))
            print(x)
            exit(x)
        else:
            print('Enter a positive value as input argument')
            exit(x)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)


if re.search('SetVelocity',sys.argv[1]):
    val = int(re.search(r'\d+', sys.argv[1]).group())

    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)
    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        x = SetVelocity(int(val))
        print(x)
        exit(x)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)

if re.search('SetAcceleration',sys.argv[1]):
    val = int(re.search(r'\d+', sys.argv[1]).group())

    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)
    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        x = SetAcceleration(int(val))
        print(x)
        exit(x)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)

if re.search('UserMove',sys.argv[1]):
    val = (re.search(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",sys.argv[1]).group())

    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)
    maxlimit = data1["MaxChart"]
    minlimit = data1["MinChart"]

    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        if data1["Calibrate"] ==1:
            if float(val) <= math.ceil(maxlimit) and float(val) >=  float(minlimit):
                x = UserMove(float(val))
                print(x)
                exit(x)
            else:
                print('Please enter the value within the max limit %d and min limit %d .' % (maxlimit, minlimit) )
                exit(4)
        else:
            print('Calibrate and set Maximum and Minumim limits in centimeters')
            exit(2)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)

if re.search('UnconditionalMove',sys.argv[1]):
    val = (re.search(r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?",sys.argv[1]).group())

    initialization(1)
    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)
    if data1["Initialize"] ==1:
        x = UnconditionalMove(float(val))
        print(x)
        exit(x)
    else:
        print('Stepper is not Initialized')
        exit(1)

if sys.argv[1] == 'Closeall()':
    closeall()

if sys.argv[1] == 'Stop()':
    Stop()
```

The UserMove() function of steppermotor.py is as below:

def UserMove(TargetPos):

```
try:
   # Initilize devices
    initialization(0)

    tem = open("count.pkl",'rb')
    data1 = pickle.load(tem)

    # For the first time reading current position of the from chart from the CalibrationMAX output and then updating current position. 
    currentPosition = data1["Max"]

    # Before move command 
    data1["ChartPreviousPosition"] = currentPosition  

    # Subtract the current position values of the chart to the user input position
    # Diff is the no of cm that motor will move  
    Diff = - float(currentPosition) + TargetPos

    # Convert into motor steps 
    g = Diff*float(840.07140)

    # set current position as start position
    stepper.setCurrentPosition(0, 0)
    encoder.setPosition(0,0)

    print("Motor will now move     %.2f  cm" % Diff)

    # Motor will now move to the target position 
    stepper.setTargetPosition(0, int(g))

    # While currentPosition !=TargetPosition
    while stepper.getCurrentPosition(0) != int(g):
        #I want to break this while loop when Stop() is executed/stopFlag==True

        if stopFlag == True:
            exit(1) #return or break
        else:
            #Update the state of the motor
            curr = stepper.getCurrentPosition(0)
            EncodEnd = encoder.getPosition(0)
            Enco = EncodEnd/4
            chartcurr = 0.001190375*curr
            chartpos = currentPosition + chartcurr
            data1.update({'MotorMovedPosition':curr})
            data1.update({'ChartMovedPosition':chartpos})
            data1.update({'Max':chartpos})
    sleep(0.2)


    # Get the postion of the stepper once it has reached target
    curr = stepper.getCurrentPosition(0)

    # Get Encoder count value, the value is in PPR 
    EncodEnd = encoder.getPosition(0)
    # convert that value into CPR 
    Enco = EncodEnd/4

    IdealEncoderCnt = Diff*39.37847

    #Check if the Encoder counts are as expected
    if abs(abs(IdealEncoderCnt) - abs(Enco)) < 4:
        print("Motor moved as expected")
    elif (abs(IdealEncoderCnt) - abs(Enco)) >=4:
        print("Motor didn't move all the way to the target position")
        return 6
    else:
        print("Motor moved beyond the target position")
        return 6

    return 0

except PhidgetException as e:
    print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))
    print("Exiting....")
    exit(1)
```

In the stop() function of steppermotor.py, I'm setting the *stopFlag=True*.
Note that the *stopFlag=False* is defined as a global variable.

I tried making the steppermotor.py multithreaded (by creatinf a thread for each function in the main script when that argument is called) and even multi-processed. But none of it seems to work when the call from MATLAB using

```
%In the MoveMotor callback function of MATLAB
system('C:\Python33\python C:\PhidgetsPython\steppermotor.py UserMove(50)');

%In the stopMotor callback function of MATLAB
system('C:\Python33\python C:\PhidgetsPython\steppermotor.py Stop())');
```

I presume that when the second system call is made from MATLAB while the first call is still executing, a different instance of the steppermotor.py is created and the memory is not shared between them. And hence, I'm unable to break out of the while loop even when the *stopFlag* is set to *True* during the 2nd system call.

Am I missing out on something obvious, or is there a workaround for this problem?

Thanks!